# How can I use multiple "Rule" keywords in Specflow (Rider)?

Tags: specflow, rider

I have this problem in Specflow for Rider. Does anyone know if there is a way to make it work? I can't find documentation. In [this specflow documentation](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Gherkin/Gherkin-Reference.html#rule) the `Rule` keyword is used two times but it doesn't mention Rider. When I try to do it in Rider I get this error. It says it expects a "RuleLine", but apparently that won't do. Only using one `Rule` works.

It works no problem in VS2022.

The `Rule` keyword hasn't been ported to Swedish, that's why the language is mixed.

[image]

Comment: This might depend on the IDE integration. If the IDE plugin has not been updated to include support for this keyword, then it won't work in Rider.

Comment: Maybe a syntax error in the last scenario of the rule above (regel 1)?

Answer (score 0):

The implemented Swedish keyword for rules is "Regel".

See gherkin-language.json: https://github.com/cucumber/common/blob/main/gherkin/gherkin-languages.json#L3050